# ListView didn't change text on app

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, android-studio

I'm building an app and I was trying to set a ListView of Items defined on a xml file. Not that hard, I thought, but I came in a very strange problem (I never figured this out) and I don't know how to solve this, although I looked up on the forum and on the net too, without any solving clue. I'll post here my code and the result on my phone, but, in a few words, my problem is that my app creates the List of Items and set the elements... But when it starts, on my mobile screen I can just see the first item with the right text setted and all the text of the other elements are not setted. If I scroll down the screen and then scroll it back up... The magic happens! All the text are well setted! Is my app joking me or there are a real error in my code?

**activity_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.mancu_000.onclickmarkerlistener.ListActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**ListActivity.java**

```
package com.example.mancu_000.onclickmarkerlistener;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        generateListContent();
        lv.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_layout, data));
    }

    private void generateListContent() {
        int i = 0;
        do {
            data.add("This is the element number " + i);
            i++;
        } while (i < 55);
    }

    private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        private int layout;

        public MyListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            layout = resource;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder mainViewHolder = null;

            if(convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                convertView = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
                ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.thumbnail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_thumbnail);
                viewHolder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text);
                viewHolder.button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_btn);
                viewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Button clicked for list item " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
            else {
                mainViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                mainViewHolder.title.setText(getItem(position));
            }

            return convertView;
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        ImageView thumbnail;
        TextView title;
        Button button;
    }
}
```

**list_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:id="@+id/list_item_thumbnail"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/list_item_text"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/list_item_thumbnail" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Okay"
        android:id="@+id/list_item_btn"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

So, when I start this activity, this is what happen on the screen:
[First image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jb9f8.jpg)

So, I scroll down the screen and then scroll it up again... And here is the magic: [Second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbJTI.jpg)

Please, help me, I'm blowing up my mind on this from days!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the `ListView` items have the default text because you never set the text when the `convertView` is null. Also the `Toast` generated when you click on a `Button` could be incorrect because you never update the message.

You need to change your code like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder mainViewHolder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
        mainViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        mainViewHolder.thumbnail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_thumbnail);
        mainViewHolder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text);
        mainViewHolder.button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_btn);

        convertView.setTag(mainViewHolder);
    } else {
        mainViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    mainViewHolder.title.setText(getItem(position));
    mainViewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Button clicked for list item " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, this is perfect working!! A really appreciate your help, you made my day!!

Answer (score 0):

just replace your getView method by the following code. definitely it will work

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.thumbnail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_thumbnail);
            viewHolder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text);
            viewHolder.button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_btn);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }

        viewHolder.title.setText(getItem(position));

        viewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Button clicked for list item " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, this is perfect working!! A really appreciate your help, you made my day!! Unfortunately I can only set one answer with the green flag, but yours is as right as the other, I would put the green on yours too if I could.